# How to grep all other characters except + and space

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I'm trying to use grep to find lines that has any other character except + and spacing.

I've tried using

`grep [^+]`

but if I test it with a text file:

```
++++++++
++++++++
+  ++ ++
```

which returns 3 empty lines.

The -c option returns 3 so I thought that spaces and newlines may be getting excluded so I tried

`grep -c [^+\ ]` and `grep -c [^+\n\ ]`

and both still gives me 3.

I've also tried

`grep -v [+]`

and though this code works with my above text file, I still need it to detect lines that also contain a mixture of +'s and other characters

For example, `+1+++++` should also be included in the search, but was excluded.

What am I missing?

For clarification, on a text file like this:

```
++++++++
+  ++ ++
+1     +
abcd fgh
++++++++
```

I want it to return

```
+1     +
abcd fgh
```

Comment: Does your file have DOS-style `\r\n` line endings?

Comment: Are you writing a Brainfuck interpreter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote your pattern! This works just fine:

```
$ grep '[^+]' file
+  ++ ++
```

Your `[^+]` is interpreted as glob range pattern if unquoted (any file not matching `+`) and processed by your shell, `grep` will see file names macthing the glob.

> In most shell implementations, one may also use ^ as the range negation character, e.g. [^[:space:]]. ([via](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob))

If you also want to exclude spaces, use `[^+ ]` as your pattern:

```
$ grep '[^+ ]' file2
+1     +
abcd fgh
```

---

You can check how your shell interprets your commands with `set -x`:

```bsh
set -x
grep [^+] file
```

Comment: That still returns +  ++ ++, though.  I want grep to return all lines that contain characters other than +.  I've edited my question for clarification.

Comment: Then you need to also exclude spaces. Space **is** a character other than `+`.

Comment: I was just about to get back with that.  It seems to be working now.  Need to do some testing to make sure results are not due to chance.

Comment: [^+ ] didn't work but including ^[:spaces:] worked.  I think.